# How to find out if my mobile data is working or defective?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-ace, mobile-data

I installed `CyanogenMod 7.2 stable` on my Samsung Galaxy Ace before, but it seems mobile data wasn't working. I decided to download the [latest nightly](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?device=cooper) build (2013-03-01) but still the mobile data doesn't work.

What are some ways to troubleshoot/test if my mobile data is working? Note: it was working before on stock ROM.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: Roaming was active. That's why mobile data wasn't working.

Simply disabling roaming fixed the issue.